# Restart list numbering in word for each new list created

Tags: css, jsp, ms-word

I am exporting content from a jsp page into MS Word using javascript.

When the user is in Word there is a table with 10 rows and 2 columns, A & B.  The user creates an ordered list in row 1, column A like this:

1 dog
  2 cat
  3 mouse

if the user then creates a second list in row 1 column B is turns out like this:

4 car
  5 truck
  6 bike

instead of:

1 car
  2 truck
  3 bike

Word is set up to continue the numbering in lists from prior lists automatically.  I know this can be reset easily but the users dont want to have to do this.  They want the numbering of any potential lists created to restarted at 1. when the document is exported into Word and opened in front of them.

So this must be set up in the javasctipt code or using a style or something prior to getting into Word.  This is what I dont know how to do.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Feena.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a named sequence rather than the in-built lists (as in inserting an instnace of the field {SEQ SequenceName} everywhere you want a number), and choose a different name for each of the different lists, it will work as you desire.

e.g.

{SEQ OpenIssueSeq} Issue 1
(SEQ OpenIssueSeq} Issue 2
etc.